# Sending Emails Using TinyMce- Angular 2

Tags: angular, tinymce

How do i bind my data that is the data from the input field (name) and data from the textarea (body) to my service and post to my server? Is there a specific way tinymce does this? The problem seems to be from my ngModel bindings to the input. What am i missing in my code please? Thanks in advance

**component**

```html
<div class="col-sm-11">
    <h1>Tiny MCe</h1>
    <label>Title</label>
    <input name="title" [(ngModel)]="editor.title" placeholder="Subject" type="text" class="form-control" required>
    <div class="tiny">
        <div id="tinyFormGroup" class="form-group">
            <div class="hidden">
                <textarea [(ngModel)]="editor.body" id="baseTextArea">{{body}}</textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" (click)="sendData()">Send</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
@Component({
    inputs: ['mceContent'],
    outputs: ['contentChanged'],
    providers:[HttpService]
})

// source of this module - 
// http://www.unitydatasystems.com/blog/2015/12/16/angular-2-tinymce-wysiwyg-editor/

export class EmailComponent {

    private elementRef: ElementRef;
    private elementID: string;



    public contentChanged: EventEmitter<any>;

    constructor(@Inject(ElementRef) elementRef: ElementRef, private httpService:HttpService)
    {
        this.elementRef = elementRef;

        var randLetter = String.fromCharCode(65 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 26));
        var uniqid = randLetter + Date.now();

        this.elementID = 'tinymce' + uniqid;
        this.contentChanged = new EventEmitter();
    }

    editor= {

       title:"",
       body: ""

    }

    ngAfterViewInit()
    {
        //Clone base textarea
        var baseTextArea = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector("#baseTextArea");
        var clonedTextArea = baseTextArea.cloneNode(true);
        clonedTextArea.id = this.elementID;

        var formGroup = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector("#tinyFormGroup");
        formGroup.appendChild(clonedTextArea);


        //Attach tinyMCE to cloned textarea
        tinymce.init(
            {


                forced_root_block : "",
                mode: 'exact',
                height: 300,

                theme: 'modern',
                plugins: [
                    'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
                    'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen template',
                    'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste code'
                ],
                toolbar: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image ',
                elements: this.elementID,
                setup: this.tinyMCESetup.bind(this)
            }
        );
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        //destroy cloned elements
        tinymce.get(this.elementID).remove();

        var elem = document.getElementById(this.elementID);
        elem.parentElement.removeChild(elem);
    }

    tinyMCESetup(ed) {
        ed.on('keyup', this.tinyMCEOnKeyup.bind(this));
    }

    tinyMCEOnKeyup(e) {
        this.contentChanged.emit(tinymce.get(this.elementID).getContent());
    }

    set mceContent(content) {
        this.body = content;
    }

    sendData(){

        this.httpService.sendEmail(this.editor)
        .subscribe(data => {

            console.log(data);
        })


    }
}
```

Comment: Off-topic, but how many user accounts do you really have Switz/Beginner/Liska Liskor? Any more than these three, just to know so I can keep count? :D

Comment: it doesn't answer my question and i basically have no idea of your off topic please :) seriously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are cloning your textarea, so there will be no `ngModel` update after that, `ngModel` is bound to an element, cloning the element won't clone the ngModel behavior. You cannot use `ngModel` on a dynamically-created element.

What I would do if I were you:

- First create a custom component input that implements [`ControlValueAccessor`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/ControlValueAccessor-interface.html) and so that can be used with `ngModel` and `formControl`.

  > ### [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/ControlValueAccessor-interface.html)
  >
  > A bridge between a control and a native element.
  >
  > A `ControlValueAccessor` abstracts the operations of writing a new value to a DOM element representing an input control.
  >
  > Please see [DefaultValueAccessor](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/DefaultValueAccessor-directive.html) for more information.
- In that component, create a tinyMCE instance on an element, on that tinyMCE instance, listen to input events and propagate the changes to the `formControl` / `ngModel`.
- then use my component like any input:
  `<my-component [(ngModel)]="myModel"></my-component>`